# Open/write deleting txt file contents?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am bassicly trying to read a number from a file, convert it to an int, add one to it,  then rewrite the new number back to the file. However every time I run this code when i open the .txt file it is blank. Any help would be appreciated thanks! I am a python newb.

```
f=open('commentcount.txt','r')
counts = f.readline()
f.close
counts1 = int(counts)
counts1 = counts1 + 1
print(counts1)
f2 = open('commentcount.txt','w') <---(the file overwriting seems to happen here?)
f2.write(str(counts1))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Having empty files

This issue is caused by you failing to close the file descriptor. You have `f.close` but it should be `f.close()` (a function call). And you also need an `f2.close()` in the end.

Without the `close` it takes a while until the contents of the buffer arrive in the file. And it is a good practice to close file descriptors as soon as they are not used.

As a side note, you can use the following syntactic sugar to ensure that the file descriptor is closed as soon as possible:

```
with open(file, mode) as f:
    do_something_with(f)
```

Now, regarding the overwriting part:

## Writing to file without overwriting the previous content.

**Short answer**: You don't open the file in the proper mode. Use the **append** mode (`"a"`).

---

**Long answer**:

It is the intended behavior. Read the following:

```
>>> help(open)
Help on built-in function open in module __builtin__:

open(...)
    open(name[, mode[, buffering]]) -> file object

    Open a file using the file() type, returns a file object.  This is the
    preferred way to open a file.  See file.__doc__ for further information.


>>> print file.__doc__
file(name[, mode[, buffering]]) -> file object

Open a file.  The mode can be 'r', 'w' or 'a' for reading (default),
writing or appending.  The file will be created if it doesn't exist
when opened for writing or appending; it will be truncated when
opened for writing.  Add a 'b' to the mode for binary files.
Add a '+' to the mode to allow simultaneous reading and writing.
If the buffering argument is given, 0 means unbuffered, 1 means line
buffered, and larger numbers specify the buffer size.  The preferred way
to open a file is with the builtin open() function.
Add a 'U' to mode to open the file for input with universal newline
support.  Any line ending in the input file will be seen as a '\n'
in Python.  Also, a file so opened gains the attribute 'newlines';
the value for this attribute is one of None (no newline read yet),
'\r', '\n', '\r\n' or a tuple containing all the newline types seen.
```

So, reading the manuals shows that if you want the content to be kept you should open in **append** mode:

```
open(file, "a")
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use the with statement. this assume that the file descriptor is closed no matter what:

```
with open('file', 'r') as fd:
    value = int(fd.read())

with open('file', 'w') as fd:
    fd.write(value + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**python open file paramters:**

`w`:

> Opens a file for writing only. Overwrites the file if the file exists.
>   If the file does not exist, creates a new file for writing.

You can use `a` (append):

> Opens a file for appending. The file pointer is at the end of the file
>   if the file exists. That is, the file is in the append mode. If the
>   file does not exist, it creates a new file for writing.

for more information you can read [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm)

One more advice is to use with:

```
with open("x.txt","a") as f:
    data = f.read()
    ............
```

**For example:**

```
with open('c:\commentcount.txt','r') as fp:
    counts = fp.readline()

counts = str(int(counts) + 1)

with open('c:\commentcount.txt','w') as fp:
    fp.write(counts)
```

Note this will work only if you have a file name `commentcount` and it has a `int` at the first line since `r` does not create new file, also it will be only one counter...it won't append a new number.

Comment: You can open the same file multiple times. You'll have different cursors inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You never close the file. If you don't properly close the file the OS might not commit any changes. To avoid this problem it is recommended that you use Python's `with` statement to open files as it it will close them for you once you are done with the file.

```
with open('my_file.txt', a) as f:
    do_stuff()
```